# Main form gets deactivated when Ok is clicked on CustomizedMessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

I have created a `CustomizedMessageBox` which is an inherited form.
I have made static `SHOW()` method in the `customizedMessageBox` which accepts title, message, icon, buttons etc.

My problem is when I click on 'OK' of `CustomizedMessageBox`, the main form from which the `CustomizedMessageBox.Show(...)` is called gets deactivated, i.e. some other application on my system gets focus.

This does not happen always but when `CustomizedMessageBox` is at least called 4-5 times. Please suggest what should I do.

I read on internet that setting `MDIParent` can solve this, but in my case, the SHOW method is static so I cannot use the MDI parent child concept for this.

Code Details are below:

```
//Calling static show method of Customized Message Box    
CustomizedMessageBox.Show("Data Not Found","Title", CustomizedMessageBox.CyButtons.Ok, CustomizedMessageBox.CyIcon.Error);    

class CustomizedMessageBox : Form    
{    

  static private CustomizedMessageBox _newMessageBox;    

  //CyButton and CyIcon are enums defined in CustomizedMessageBox class    
  static public DialogResult Show(string message, string title, CyButtons mButtons, CyIcon mIcon)    
  {    
   //Build Message Box by setting properties of "_newMessageBox"    
   _newMessageBox.ShowDialog();    
   //return DiaglogResult    
  }    
}
```

Comment: Please show (!) the relevant code.

Comment: Hi, scanning .... no code? I'm leaving.

Comment: Hi, any other code details required?

Comment: Please check if there are any events (OnClose, OnDeactivate etc) are handled.

Comment: This happens when you set the Enabled property to false yourself instead of leaving it up to ShowDialog().  Your snippet is insufficient to diagnose that or recommend an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a DialogResult and once OK is clicked give your parent focus again. For example

```
if (CustomizedMessageBox.Show() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   this.Focus();
}
```